# bootstrap sidebar can't get selected item caret icon to rotate by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a sidebar with pages hidden under expandable items. If you click the 'contact' item in my example the caret icon rotates correctly. If I'm on a page under an expandable item, I want that item to already be expanded when you visit the page. In my example it's demonstrating when you are currently on the 'tagger.site' page. I'm trying to get my projects dropdown to be expanded with the icon rotated correctly by default when you load the page.

I want my page's icon to be pointing up for the expanded projects tab like in this image below:

[image]

So I added the class 'opened-tab' to the projects tab, and added the css:

```
.opened-tab:after{
                transform: rotate(90deg); 
            }
            .opened-tab:after { 
                transition: 0.4s; 
            }
```

to my jsfiddel code below:
https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/b4z735tk/55/

Which gives the rotate icon the correct orientation on page load, but now is unable to rotate correctly when clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `aria-expanded="false"` to `aria-expanded="true"` in your html code.

```
  <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle opened-tab">Projects</a>
```

I hope this is what you are expecting. check out my answer in full-page view.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

/*
#sidebar ul li a:hover { background: rgb(6, 255, 193); color: rgb(247, 1, 255); } `;
*/

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    /*
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin-right: 77px;
    */
    /* background: rgb(11, 223, 212); */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-left:11px
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*  background: #63c23e; NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        color: pink
        display: inline;
    }
}

#imageModal{
    z-index:3;
}

/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */
#sidebarCollapse{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    margin-left: 84%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0 ,0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Bottom of sidebar image stuff */
.responsive {
    width: 90%;
    bottom:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

/* image footer color text center */
.sidebar-footer{
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.1rem;
/*font-family:'Consolas' */
}

/* image footer color boxes */
.colorBox {
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel='icon' href='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/48-bubbles/48/06.Tags-512.png' type='image/x-icon' />
    <title>tagger.site</title>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>


<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
    
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar" style='background: #99c9f4; color:#000000;'>

        <!-- sidenav top title -->
        <div id='sidebarTop' class="sidebar-header" style='background: #3c414e'>
            <!-- sidebar top title text -->
            <h3 style='color: #ffffff' style='font-weight: bold; text-size:12px'><strong>Title</strong></h3> 
            <!-- sidebar expand/collapse button -->
            <button id='sidebarCollapse'>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/24/000000/menu.png"/>
            </button> 
        </div>
        
        <!-- dropdown caret rotate style code -->
        <style>
            .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
            transform: rotate(180deg); 
            }

            /*for animation*/ 
            .dropdown-toggle:after { 
            transition: 0.4s; 
            }

 
        </style>
       

        <!-- sidenav list of items -->
        <ul class="list-unstyled components sideBarOption" style='background: #0c3489; color: #ffffff;'>
            <!-- about page -->
            <li>
                <a 
                href="/" class='navbarItem'>About
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- projects dropdown -->
            <li>
                <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle opened-tab">Projects</a>
                
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled show " id="projectsSubmenu">
                    <!-- tagger.site -->
                    <li>
                        <a style='background: #a0b4cc; color: #ffffff;' href="/tagger" class='navbarItem'>tagger.site</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- popularify.site -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="/popularify">popularify.biz</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- electron-upload-tool -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="/electron-upload-tool">electron-upload-tool</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- contact dropdown -->
            <li>
                <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Email</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Github</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


        </ul>
```